# KKT Conditions for Minmax Problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^m$.
Now 
$$f\left(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\right):\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
is convex in $\mathbf{x}$ and concave in $\mathbf{y}$. The problem is to find
$$\mbox{min}_{\mathbf{x}}\mbox{max}_{\mathbf{y}}f\left(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\right)$$
constrained by $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{F}_1\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{y}\in\mathcal{F}_2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$. $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are convex sets. 
Obviously the problem can be tackled in two steps as optimisations with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$. But is there any way to formulate a Lagrangian dual and KKT conditions at a single go?

Answer (score 0):

Since the inner problem $\min_y -f(x,y)$ is convex,
the first-order conditions are necessary and sufficient for optimality.
These optimality conditions have $x$ as a parameter.
Hence, you can rewrite your problem as
\begin{align*}\min & \quad f(x,y)\\
\text{such that}&\quad y \text{ satisfies the opt. cond. of the inner problem with parameter } x\end{align*}
If your set $F_2$ is given by equality and inequality constraints, the first-order conditions become the KKT conditions.
If only equality constraints are present in $F_2$, the rewritten problem becomes a classical NLP and you can write down its KKT conditions.
However, if inequality constraints are included in $F_2$, the KKT conditions will include complementarity conditions like $g(y) \ge 0$, $\lambda \ge 0$ and $\lambda \, g(y) = 0$, and the rewritten problem becomes a *mathematical program with complementarity constraints* (MPCC). This type of problems have severe difficulties: MFCQ is violated at every feasible point and KKT multipliers may not exist. For further reading, I suggest [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3690420?uid=36480&uid=3737864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=67&uid=36479&uid=62&uid=5910216&sid=21102728637673) and [the papers by C. Kanzow](http://www.mathematik.uni-wuerzburg.de/~kanzow/).